# UIButton gets created twice on cell reload

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` inside a `UITableViewCell`. When the app is first launched, it works as expected, where I created it's frame.

When I scroll pass the cell which holds the button, it creates a second instance of the button slightly below the button.
Here's a video to illustrate my problem: http://pixori.al/DJ1k

Here's the code for the `UITableViewCell` and also how I populate the cells.
Not sure why it's behaving like this.

```
#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

// 3 sections, (1 = mistarOverview) (2 = hourlyForecast) (3 = dailyForecast)
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) {
        return MAX(6,6) + 1; //TODO add getNumberOfClasses for people with 7 or 8 classes
    } else if (section == 1) {
        return MIN([[MAManager sharedManager].hourlyForecast count], 6) + 1;
    } else {
        return MIN([[MAManager sharedManager].dailyForecast count], 6) + 1;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Redefine layout variables in method from `viewDidLoad`
    CGFloat inset = 20; // For padding


    if (! cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Sets up attributes of each cell
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; //TODO none
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.2];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    QBFlatButton* loginButton = nil;

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            [self configureHeaderCell:cell title:@"Grades"];

            if ([cell.textLabel.text isEqual: @"Grades"] && (!loginButton) && (indexPath.row == 0) && (indexPath.section == 0)) {

                UIView *cellView = cell.contentView;
                CGRect loginButtonFrame = CGRectMake((cellView.frame.size.width - (80 + inset)), 18, 80, (cellView.frame.size.height));
                loginButton = [[QBFlatButton alloc] initWithFrame:loginButtonFrame];
                [loginButton addTarget:self action:@selector(loginButtonWasPressed)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                loginButton.faceColor = [UIColor grayColor];
                loginButton.sideColor = [UIColor clearColor];

                loginButton.radius = 6.0;
                loginButton.margin = 4.0;
                loginButton.depth = 3.0;
                loginButton.alpha = 0.3;

                loginButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:20];
                [loginButton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [loginButton setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [cellView addSubview:loginButton];
            }
        } else {
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Period %ld               A+", (long)indexPath.row];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Class name";
            //TODO get grades and config using method (TB Created)
        }
    } else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            [self configureHeaderCell:cell title:@"Hourly Forecast"];
        }
        else {
            // Get hourly weather and configure using method
            MACondition *weather = [MAManager sharedManager].hourlyForecast[indexPath.row - 1];
            [self configureHourlyCell:cell weather:weather];
        }
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            [self configureHeaderCell:cell title:@"Daily Forecast"];
        }
        else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
            // Get daily weather and configure using method
            MACondition *weather = [MAManager sharedManager].dailyForecast[indexPath.row - 1];
            [self configureDailyCell:cell weather:weather];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I was just reading around, maybe it's something to do with cell reuse? Because sometimes when the other cells load it shows up in cells as I scroll further down.

Comment: I don't think I have a `prepareForReuse` for the cells

Comment: @NeverHopeless It's a `QBFlatButton` called loginButton

Comment: You are right. Cells are getting reused and when you first get an already used cell this cell already has a button. You should always "clean" the cells before reusing them (e.g. by setting all properties to nil before you re-set them in `cellForRowArIndexPath:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the following UITableView Delegate Method

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//In here, check the index path. When you have the cell that contains the button, pop it out from there by using [button removeFromSuperView];
}
```

Your problem occurs when you dequeue the cell. Since the cell is being reused, it already has the button and you're simply re-adding it again. This will solve your issue. However, I'd recommend you create a subclass for the UITableViewCell, and in it's prepareForReuse method, pop the button out. Up to you. Both will work.

Comment: I've created a subclass here https://github.com/AndrewSB/MistarApp/blob/master/MistarApp/MistarApp/MistarApp/MAGradeCell.m, what else do I need to add to it to remove the reuse identifier problem?

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry, I still can't figure out how to make the custom `UIableViewCell`

Comment: You have already made a custom subclass of your UITableViewCell. Can you direct me to the file where the OP's code is?

Comment: Right now, the cells are empty. While moving the assignments of grades and weathers to the `.textLabel.text`'s are empty. 

The custom `UITableCell` is here https://github.com/AndrewSB/MistarApp/blob/master/MistarApp/MistarApp/MistarApp/MAGradeCell.m

and the main view controller is here https://github.com/AndrewSB/MistarApp/blob/master/MistarApp/MistarApp/MistarApp/MAController.m

Comment: Where ever you're using `[cellView addSubview:someview];`, you should replace it with `[self.contentView addSubView:someview];` 

In line 30, you create a copy of the cell's view and subviews to it. That wouldn't work, as you're not replacing the cell's content view with that copy.

Comment: This is the current behavior http://pixori.al/UdVz 
So the first login button should be there, it shouldn't be recreated on every following page.
Then, (at the end) in the grade table, when I refresh those cells icons are added that (I think) persist from when the cells were displaying weather data. 
Also, the login button is created again, slightly below the first one

Comment: Line 30 of which file?

Comment: Of the cell's .m file.

Comment: This one? https://github.com/AndrewSB/MistarApp/blob/master/MistarApp/MistarApp/MistarApp/MAGradeCell.m#L30

Comment: Ohk, my bad. I was referencing the wrong file. Let me post back with an update in a bit.

Comment: ohk, when you initialize your cell, you must create all the default labels by your self. That also includes your custom button. You can refer to this : http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/ or http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702

Answer (score 1):

Table view cells are not just deallocated then they move out of visible area. They are stored for reusing and then returned in `tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`

So you need to clean your cells after using or before reusing. There are several ways:

1.Add tag to your button when you create it

```
loginButton.tag = SOME_TAG;
```

just after

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

search for view with this tag

```
loginButton = [cell viewWithTag:SOME_TAG];
```

if `loginButton != nil` you can reuse it or remove from cell and then create a new one.

2.Implement UITableViewDelegate method

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndDisplayingCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and erase login button inside it.

3.Create custom [UITableViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html)class and implement `prepareForReuse` method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22602745/uibutton-gets-created-twice-on-cell-reload/22602868?noredirect=1#comment34414452_22602868
How would I do *3.*?

Comment: Please look here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html There are links to several examples how to work with UITableViewCell

Comment: Here's my custom `UITableViewCell` https://github.com/AndrewSB/MistarApp/blob/master/MistarApp/MistarApp/MistarApp/MAGradeCell.m, what else should I add to it?

Comment: I can not see `loginButtonWasPressed` method implementation but everything else looks good.

Comment: It's still having the strange behavior, one sec, I'll show you

Comment: So the first login button should be there, it shouldn't be recreated on every following page. Then, (at the end) in the grade table, when I refresh those cells icons are added that (I think) persist from when the cells were displaying weather data. Also, the login button is created again, slightly below the first one

Comment: In your code from github in `- (void)prepareForReuse` move `[loginButton removeFromSuperview];` to the top, before 'self.loginButton = nil; loginButton = nil;'. Because now `[loginButton removeFromSuperview];` is called for nil object and has no effect.

Comment: Sorry. Have no idea. May be you should open new, more specific question for your problem. Also if you found my answer helpful please upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the button every time you return a cell in this method. If you scroll the cell off the screen and back on, this method is called again for the same index path, and you will add the button again.

You declare the variable, do nothing with it, then check if it is nil. It will always be nil, so you always add the button.

A quick and dirty solution is to give the button a tag, then check for its existence using `viewWithTag:`.

A better solution is to make a custom cell subclass, and set one-time properties like this in the init method. Your cell contents seem very different for each section as well, so use different reuse identifiers for each section, and possibly a different cell subclass. Clearing out sub views is expensive and could hurt your scrolling performance.

Comment: Thanks, the same thing happens with some of the other cells. -> http://pixori.al/tmBM
How would I do a custom cell subclass? What should I include in it?

Comment: The same way you do any other subclass. Xcode has a template with the correct initialiser method already populated.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your project first time then cellForRowAtIndexPath is called.....
Then whenever you scroll tableView it again calls cellForRowAtIndexPath and reload data automatically..
So you have to take CellIdentifier as unique for each cell.

you have to remove static keyword from

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
```

now you have

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
```

only this things

Now you have to write like below

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",indexPath];
```

Now Enjoy.....